# Can’t filter table based on select box

Tags: angularjs

I have a table I wish to filter with a select box. If I try to filter it with an `<input>`, it works great. But when I do it with a `<select>`, the table gets empty. I've commented out the `<input>`, which works. Any ideas why I can’t filter with select?

```html
<fieldset ng-controller="DimensionListCtrl">
  Pipe: <select ng-model="query2.code" 
            ng-options="pipe.code for pipe in pipes"></select>
  <!-- Search: <input ng-model="query2.code">  -->
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Pipe title</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Inner diameter</th>
      <th>Outer diameter</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="dimension in dimensions |filter:query2">
      <td>{{dimension.code}}</td>
      <td>{{dimension.title_en}}</td>
      <td>{{dimension.nominalsize}}</td>
      <td>{{dimension.innerdiameter}}</td>
      <td>{{dimension.outerdiameter}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Think you could provide a plnkr / jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the correct model, it's a select, so you don't need to suffix it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/PTJ390DpRlOev9tjcKJY?p=preview

Comment: Can't see any other diffrence than the column specification is removed (query2.code -> query2)? Still doesn't work for me. I've also tried to hard code the options in the select. No difference.

Comment: Well i wish to filter only on the first column. But i tried removing it and it was no luck.